# How can I upload files to my computer from my smartphone via FTP without WWW?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

Basic FTP works like this:

1. upload files to a server
2. login to the server via an FTP client from another device
3. download the uploaded file

However, what if I want to transfer files from my smartphone (or tablet) to my computer system?

I have a client on my tablet, I just need a location where I can point to, but here's where I get confused. I have to upload to a PC, not a server...

Comment: why not just use dropbox, copy or google drive?

Comment: Is that how you guys answer here? Of course I can, and I even do.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try reading and working through [this](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/setting-up-a-ftp-server-on-your-home-computer/)

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-up-an-FTP-server-using-filezilla/ http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-make-local-ftp-server-in-windows-7

Comment: You may include in your question what your tried or why you dont want to use certain services. If you did so it would be more clear why you dont want to do it "the easy way".

Comment: I really don't think that matters at all. It's a question and there needs to be a solution. "Why I don't want to do it the easy way" can have a very specific reason, not good for anybody.